# Listing items in a sequence

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

can someone please help me with this.This is an example of creating List. The items are numbered as 1, 2, 3 ... The issue I am facing is, when I delete any items from the list, the numbering doesn't get re-arranged. For example if  there are 7 items in the list 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and if I delete any item for example: number 3 and 6, the list appears as 1, 2, 4, 5, 7. How can I re-arrange this list after deleting so that the items are numbered serially such as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 instead of 1, 2, 4, 5, 7.

```
    import SwiftUI
struct Calculation: View {
    
    @State var load1 = Float()
    @State var load2 = Float()
    @State var gp : Float = 0
    @State var rate: Float = 0
    @ObservedObject var taskStore = TaskStore()
    @State  private var count: Double = 1
    
    func addNewToDo() {
        
        taskStore.tasks.append(Task(id: String(taskStore.tasks.count + 1), toDoItem: " \(count) Earning: =  \(rate.description)" ))
        
    }
    func stepcount() {
       
        count += 1
        
    }
    var body: some View {
        
        
        NavigationView {
            
            
            VStack {
                
                
                List {
                    
                    Section(header:Text("load 2"))
                    {
                        TextField("Enter value of load 1", value: $load1, format: .number)
                        
                        TextField("Enter value of load 1", value: $load2, format: .number)
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Button(String(format: "Add Load"), action:
                                {
                            
                            print("pay for the shift is ")
                            print(Rocky(mypay: rate))
                            gp += rate
                        })
                        
                        Button(action: {addNewToDo();stepcount(); Rocky(mypay: rate) }, label: {
                            Text(" ")
                            
                        })
                    }
                    
                    ForEach(self.taskStore.tasks) {
                        task in
                        Text(task.toDoItem)
                    }.onMove(perform : self.move)
                        .onDelete(perform : self.delete) //For each
                    
                }.navigationBarTitle("SHIFTS")
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton()) //List
                Text("Gross Pay = $\(gp) ")
                
            }.onAppear()
            
        } }
    
    func Rocky(mypay: Float)
    { rate = load1 + load2
        print("Sus \(gp)")
        
    }
    func move(from source : IndexSet, to destination : Int)
    {
        taskStore.tasks.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
    func delete(at offsets : IndexSet) {
        
        taskStore.tasks.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        
        gp -= rate
    }
    
}

struct BlueTwoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Calculation()
    }
}
```

Here is another file:

```
    import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var gp : Float = 0
    @Published var Homevariable = Bool()
}

struct Task : Identifiable {
    var id = String()
    var toDoItem = String()
    var amount : Float = 0 
}

class TaskStore : ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks = [Task]()
}
```

Comment: The number is part of the description of a task so you have made things hard for yourself, you would need to change all Task objects in your list. Does the number (count) really have to be part of the Task description, couldn’t it only be a separate value you show next to a Task? Also it might be confusing for the user if other tasks change when they delete one of them.

Comment: That makes sense, but is there any possibility to create a list both in vertical and horizontal way? For example can I present the list such as there are three in the first row and then every time the users click the add shift button, the shift comes in the 2nd row. Such as item 1, 2, 3 are in first row and then 4, 5, 6 are in second row and it continues.

Comment: That sounds more like you want to use a `Dictionary` defined something like `[Shift:[Task]` to keep the tasks with the shift, but it is pretty unclear of what you are looking for.